# Some help installing pgrouting_dd on mac os x

Tags: pgrouting, installation

I hope someone may be able to help me but i've been grapling for hours trying to install pgrouting with Driving Time to no success. I have been able to build pg routing no problem.

However if i trying to cmake with the -DWITH_DD=ON flag set when performing the make I get the following and it fails:

```
[ 10%] Building C object         extra/driving_distance/src/CMakeFiles/routing_dd.dir/alpha.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object extra/driving_distance/src/CMakeFiles/routing_dd.dir/alpha_drivedist.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object extra/driving_distance/src/CMakeFiles/routing_dd.dir/boost_drivedist.o
[ 40%] Building C object  extra/driving_distance/src/CMakeFiles/routing_dd.dir/drivedist.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../../lib/librouting_dd.dylib
```

Undefined symbols:....

Does anyone have any ideas on how to overcome this?

I should also point out that I am using os x 10.6.x

C

Comment: Did you try using the version provided by KyngChaos compiled fro OSX? http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres

Comment: Ah brilliant I had tried the dmg for pgrouting not noticing that it was for pgsql 9.1 and not 9.2 as I had installed. So removed 9.2 and installed 9.1. bobs your uncle it's all working now.

Thanks a mill for you help!